# Flash Builder 4 Documentation Error?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-builder

still getting use to Flash Builder.

i'm writing pure ActionScript, without MXML, to create AIR applications.

when i try to reference the documentation by Command + Clicking on code (in this case i Command + Clicked on "Sprite") i receive the following error:

> Source could not be found for
>   flash.display.Sprite in
>   /Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4/
>   sdks/4.1.0/frameworks/libs/air/airglobal.swc

i'm trying to launch the Adobe Help application, if it's not already open, and display the appropriate documentation.  same this as if i had Right-Clicked on some code in Flash Professional CS5 and select View Help from the popup list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Shift + F2`  To change it, go to window -> preferences -> general -> keys.

Answer (score 1):

Command clicking on a class name takes you to its source file. Cmd-clicking any class you wrote yourself or have .as files for in your source path, will do that but for the built-in classes that live inside swcs you don't have the source. So that's what the error tells you.

New in FlashBuilder4 is the ASDoc window that will show you documentation for the class that your cursor is near (don't know how to phrase that accurately).

What is sadly missing as far as I know from FB4 is the help section containing the ActionScript dictionary. Only online but not as easily usable as context-help was in FB3.

Comment: I stand corrected on the ActionScript Reference being missing from FB4.

Comment: ahhh, thanks for clearing that up for me (about Command + Click).  now the error makes sense.